# Forms creation and destroying in OnMouseEnter ; OnMouseLeave events in Delphi

Tags: delphi, events, forms, dynamic, controls

Sorry if there is already made such question earlier, but I have no time at the moment to dig in stackoverflow db ...

So, I have this code:

```
procedure TForm1.GraphPrevBtnMouseEnter(Sender: TObject);
var frm_PrevBtn : TForm;
begin
  GraphPrevBtn.Width := 75;
  if z = 0 then begin
    frm_PrevBtn := TForm.Create(nil);
    with frm_PrevBtn do begin
      Name := 'frm_PrevBtn';
      BorderStyle := bsNone;
      Position := poDesigned;
      Top := Form1.Top + GraphprevBtn.Top + (form1.Height - Form1.ClientHeight) - 3;
      Left := Form1.Left + GraphprevBtn.Left + 3;
      Width := GraphprevBtn.Width; Height := GraphprevBtn.Height; transparentColor := True; TransparentColorValue := clbtnFace;
      Show;
    end;
    GraphPrevBtn.Parent := frm_PrevBtn;
    if GetLastError = 0 then z := frm_prevBtn.GetHashCode;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.GraphPrevBtnMouseLeave(Sender: TObject);
    var frm_PrevBtn_H : THandle;
    begin
    // if form is created then- if mouse is under button then- if z = formshashcode ( form is on creatin stage )
      if not (FindVCLWindow(Mouse.CursorPos) = GraphPrevBtn) and ((FindControl(FindWindow('TForm','frm_PrevBtn')) as TForm).Visible = True) and (GraphPrevBtn.Parent = FindControl(FindWindow('TForm','frm_PrevBtn')) as TForm) then begin // if mouse is not under graphprevBtn
        ShowMessage(FindVCLWindow(Mouse.CursorPos).Name); // 
        if z = 112                                                       // then if form is created
        then begin
            GraphPrevBtn.Parent := Form1;
            GraphPrevBtn.bringtoFront;
            GraphPrevBtn.Top := 29; GraphPrevBtn.Left := 226;
            (FindControl(FindWindow('TForm','frm_PrevBtn')) as TForm).Free;
            if GetLastError = 0 then z := 0;
          end;
      end;
   end;
```

So, my wish is the following:
When I enter this GraphPrevBtn with mouse, form is created. As for is created, the focus goes from Control to new form. As focus is to new form, the *OnMouseLeave* event is fired. As event is fired, it should destroy the form, BUT **ONLY IF** user ( **NOT** *active control / focus* ) actually leaves control by mouse.

What happens now is that either new forms is not destroyed at all ***or*** both events goes infinite loop ( *frm_PrevBtn* is created and destroyed again and again and again...).

What would be best solution?

My idea is to get new forms rect and check whenever mouse is inside this rect. If it is, then perform allow *OnMouseLeave* event, otherwise deattach it ... would it work?

As much I tried with these samples:

1. http://delphi.about.com/od/windowsshellapi/a/get-active-ctrl.htm
2. http://delphi.about.com/od/delphitips2010/qt/is-some-delphi-tcontrol-under-the-mouse.htm

   - No luck. Where is the problem ... ?

*Remarks: global var z : byte;*

P.S. *Thanks for negative votes ... great motivation to use this site in future ...*

Comment: Minus for an otherwise legitimate question for "I have no time to dig in stackoverflow". If you have no time for that, why would anyone have time to read your question?

Comment: Because I checked all proposed question when inputting this I and they did not match my issue. Besides - please note that I write stackoverflow DB ... if I would not do any search, I would not bother writing "DB" in the end ;)

Comment: @HX_unbanned: There is no use adding a comment like "Anyone ... please?". Most (almost all) questions at SO get answered, and most of them get answered rather soon, by the volunteers (such as yourself) at this site, when someone gets an idea and has time for it. No user will answer a question faster simply because the OP requests it.

Comment: @HX_unbanned: it's not a problem of whether you searched or not (many don't, unfortunately). But writing "I have no time to search, so I'm going to potentially waste your time by asking already answered question" is rude. I think it's common sense.

Comment: True. But - DO NOT USE term "waste of time". You actually offend all people here pointing out that helping people is "waste of time". That is rude, too ;) Peace, college ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mouse enters on 'GraphPrevBtn', you create a form over the button. As soon as this form becomes visible, since mouse is not anymore over 'GraphPrevBtn', 'OnMouseLeave' is fired. You destroy the new form and now mouse is again on the button so 'OnMouseEnter' is fired, hence the infinite loop.

As a solution, you can move the form disposing code to 'OnMouseEnter' of Form1:

```
procedure TForm1.FormMouseEnter(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if z = 112
  then begin
    GraphPrevBtn.Parent := Form1;
    [...]
```

.. and what's with the 'GetLastError', it seems fully irrelevant. If you're going to use it, at least set last error to '0' by calling `GetLastError` or `SetLastError`before beginning your operation.

Comment: Yes, Thank you for answer. It seems like I am forced to this solution even if handling disposal on Form1 can cause big problems in future ...

Comment: @HX - What kind of problems do you expect to encounter? Anyway, alternatively you can [`Release`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Forms_TCustomForm_Release.html) the floating form in the 'OnMouseLeave' event of that form. I don't see an immediate advantage though..

Comment: I expect problems mainly within MDI /TDI functionality implementations in future. I have two DXE projects under development now and app using this code will be used as Child, therefore all VCL Forms / Application event handling would be better to be processed by MDI Parent ...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something more like this will help you:

```
var
  frm_PrevBtn : TForm = nil;

procedure TForm1.GraphPrevBtnMouseEnter(Sender: TObject); 
var
  P: TPoint;
begin 
  GraphPrevBtn.Width := 75; 
  if frm_PrevBtn = nil then begin 
    P := GraphPrevBtn.ClientOrigin;
    frm_PrevBtn := TForm.Create(nil);
    with frm_PrevBtn do begin
      BorderStyle := bsNone; 
      Position := poDesigned; 
      SetBounds(P.X, P.Y, GraphPrevBtn.Width, GraphPrevBtn.Height);
      TransparentColor := True;
      TransparentColorValue := clBtnFace; 
      GraphPrevBtn.Parent := frm_PrevBtn;
      GraphPrevBtn.Top := 0;
      GraphPrevBtn.Left := 0;
      Show; 
    end;
  end; 
end; 

procedure TForm1.GraphPrevBtnMouseLeave(Sender: TObject); 
begin 
  if (FindVCLWindow(Mouse.CursorPos) <> GraphPrevBtn) and (frm_PrevBtn <> nil) then begin
    GraphPrevBtn.Parent := Self;
    GraphPrevBtn.BringToFront; 
    GraphPrevBtn.Top := 29;
    GraphPrevBtn.Left := 226; 
    FreeAndNil(frm_PrevBtn);
  end; 
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do it like this:

1. MainForm.OnMouseOver: Create a secondary form.
2. SecondaryForm.OnMouseOver: Set FLAG_ON_SECONDARY.
3. SecondaryForm.OnMouseLeave: Clear FLAG_ON_SECONDARY.
4. MainForm.OnMouseLeave: if not FLAG_ON_SECONDARY then destroy the secondary form.

This might not work in case SecondaryForm.OnMouseOver fires after MainForm.OnMouseLeave. Well, think of something similar. Another solution is to start a timer which destroys SecondaryForm and disables itself if mouse is neither on Main nor on SecondaryForm.

Comment: thanks for your time, but this is event overkill for such small functionality ;)